# ARM language which returns the cube root

Tags: arm

VSQRT.F64 D0,D0 returns the square root of double D0 and saves it to D0 in arm code(I am using raspberry pi to compile .s file) what code can be used which returns the cube root of D0?

Answer (score 0):

There is no arm assembly instruction that computes the cube root. If you're using a normal Linux environment (on a raspberry pi) you probably have a C library in the system (glibc). That should provide the `cbrt` function that you could call from assembly: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/cbrt

Comment: Is there any way we can compute cube root or nth root in ARM assembly language?

Comment: Of course, that's exactly what the compiler is doing. You could look at its output if you want to see how it does it.